# Protractor coverage not generating report

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, test-coverage, test-reporting

Backend of our app is in `PHP` and for frontend we are using `AngularJs`.
We successfully managed to run e2e tests on local as well as on production server using `protractor`.

After writing loads of e2e tests for our app, we started looking for its coverage similar to that of unit testing. After searching for lot, luckily we find https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-coverage , exactly what we wanted.

I took help from http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/04/measuring-code-coverage-by-protractor/ article which beautifully helps in setting up everything. I setup the config and other grunt tasks for my app, and finally our code(js files) were properly instrumented. I copied the rest of the files(html, static, etc.) to that instrumented code and provided the correct path for the `proractor-config` file. Tests started running as they were running before, but this time with instrumented files.

Till this point, everything is `OK`. But when the task for generating `coverage-report` was executed, we figured that we had empty `coverage.json` file `{}`. This means the report will surely be empty as it reads that file to generate report, and as far as I have figured out, this file is generated by `protractor-coverage` grunt task while tests are executing. It sends the information to the collector(port: `3001`) using a `POST` req and while generating report, a `GET` req is being made to the same collector.

So, what I figured is, No `POST` req is being made to collector.

```
var options = {
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: <%=collectorPort%>,
  path: '/data',
  method: 'POST',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type':'application/json'
  }
};
function saveCoverage(data){
  var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      });
  });
  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });

  // write data to request body
  req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  req.write('\n');
  req.end();
}
```

Each time it just shows [image]
where it should have listed down every file: [image]

**And also**, that `100` everywhere is misleading, I ran tests for the source code: http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/04/measuring-code-coverage-by-protractor/ as explained, but even if there's only one e2e test, the report must have given the actual numbers instead of giving a straight `100` for all.

It might happen that I have some wrong configuration or missed something.

Below are my files:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist-test',
      e2e: 'coverage/e2e',
      instrumentedServer: 'coverage/server/instrument',
      instrumentedE2E: 'coverage/e2e/instrumented'
    },
    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      coverageE2E: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.e2e %>/'],
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      coverageE2E: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.e2e %>/instrumented/app',
          src: [
            '**/*',
            '!modules/**/*.js',
            '!editor/**/*.js'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.e2e %>/instrumented/app/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, ]
      },
    },

    // start - code coverage settings
    instrument: {
      files: ['app/modules/**/*.js', 'app/editor/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        lazy: true,
        basePath: 'coverage/e2e/instrumented/'
      }
    },

    makeReport: {
      src: '<%= yeoman.instrumentedE2E %>/*.json',
      options: {
        type: 'html',
        dir: '<%= yeoman.e2e %>/reports',
        print: 'detail',
        //        type: 'lcov'
        //        dir: 'reports'
      }
    },


    protractor_coverage: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'test/e2e/protractor-config.js', // Default config file
        keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
        noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
        coverageDir: '<%= yeoman.instrumentedE2E %>',
        args: {},
        run: {}
      },
      chrome: {
        options: {
          args: {
            baseUrl: 'https://localapp.vwo.com/v3/#/',
            // Arguments passed to the command
            'browser': 'chrome'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'clean:coverageE2E',
    'copy:coverageE2E',
    'instrument',
    'protractor_coverage:chrome',
    'makeReport'
  ]);
};
```

And my `coverage.json` file:

```
{}
```